# angular client fails to display images from express nodejs backend using upload path

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

This problem of displaying images on the angular client has disturbed me for long time, even after reading many similar questions. files are uploaded successful to the upload folder and the file details are stored in the mongodb database.

This is angular client. angular v1.6 after loading image data service or factory.

```
$scope.attachImages.push({
    name: attachment.originalName,
    filePath:attachment.upload_path
  })
```

Then the html web page has this where I use the ng-src for image upload path.

```
<div layout = "column" ng-repeat ="image in attachImages">
               <h5>{{image.name}}</h5>
                 <img ng-src="{{image.filePath}}"/>
            </div>
```

But this is the error I get where it cannot load the images:

> GET http://localhost:3010/client/upload/attachment/lion.jpg 404 (Not
>   Found)

this is what i did on the express nodejs backend server

```
router.get('/attachments/:cardId', function(req,res){
   //load teh attachemnts from the db... imageId,
   /// To get all the images/files stored in MongoDB
    Attachment.find({card: req.params.cardId}, function(err,images){
         if (err) {
            res.json({"success": false, "message": 'Error finding the attachments'})
         } else {
           res.json({"success": true, "message": images})
```

//for teh single image..
router.get('/attachments/:cardId/:attachmentId',function(req,res){

```
           Attachment.findOne({_id: req.params.attachmentId}, function(err, image){
                if (err) {
                    res.json({"success": false, "message": 'ERror in finding the image'})
                } else {
                     if (image) { //atleast there z content
                        //set the content-type correctly so our client or browser know how to handle it.
                         res.setHeader('Content-Type', image.mime);
                        //fs.createReadStream(path.join(UPLOAD_PATH, result.filename)).pipe(res);
                         //fs.createReadStream(path.join()).pipe(res);
                          res.send(image.upload_path);
                     }else {
                       res.json({"success": true, "message": 'No image data found'})
                     }
                }
           })

      });
```

Please any help will be appreciated... Then later I'm going to talk about createObjectURL method, which does not show anything except gibberished arrays data.

Comment: It seems my upload_path for the images cannot be opened  because iam getting this error.  Error: ENOENT, open '/home/goldsoft25/Desktop/python/angular-express-starter/asana/taskban/routes/uploads/attachment/1507923890803-lion.jpg'

Answer (score 0):

I realised that i had made a mistake on the filePath while loading the images.
it is better for one to first test whether you can load images in the browser from their upload path first before sending the images.
just putting this express static handler before loading routes saved me after struggling for  a week trying to load images.

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/client'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/client/upload/attachment'));
```

then load the express routes

```
//var user = require('./routes/user') //user routes 
board = require('./routes/board'),
```

then on the angular client

```
if(attachName.match(/\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$/)){ //u borrowed this from helper in nodejs
                                      //console.log('yeah it z the image')
                                      //$scope.attachImages.push(attachment);
                                       $scope.attachImages.push({
                                           name: attachment.originalName,
                                           imageUrl: attachment.upload_path
                                       })
```